# the method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I input the following code into Eclipse I get the following error
"the method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner"
I am new to java any help is much appreciated

```
public class Scanner{

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner person = new Scanner();
        System.out.print("Enter age: " );
        int age = person.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter gender male/female: ");
        String gender = person.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't name your class `Scanner`.

Comment: This is also why you're able to instantiate a `Scanner` with an empty constructor.  The actual `Scanner` won't let you do that.

Comment: You called your own class `Scanner`, so you're shadowing the actual `java.util.Scanner` class that contains the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classname is `Scanner`. You should rename your class as `ScannerTest` and `import java.util.Scanner;` Also pass `System.in` as parameter to your `Scanner`class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

     public static void main(String[]args) {

            Scanner person = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter age: " );
            int age = person.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter gender male/female: ");
            String gender = person.nextLine();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. first thing is you need to change your class name.
2. Then type `import java.util.Scanner;` above your class
3. Then you need to add `system.in` as `new Scanner(system.in);`

my trial:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner person = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter age: " );
         int age = person.nextInt();

         System.out.print("Enter gender male/female: ");
         String gender = person.nextLine();

    }

}
```